# How can I find removable plugs for standard pin headers?

Tags: pins, polarity, plug, header

I'm making a right angle adapter for a module with a 2x10 pin layout that has one blocked.

How can I find the little plastic pins to block a hole, ideally ones that are removable? I realize I could just put glue or something in there, but it would be nice to be able to pull out later if possible.

Edit: there is an existing answer with a minimum order of $1088.78 US - so I would be looking for somewhere that sold in sufficiently low quantities to be under $10.

[image: TPM 20-1 Header]

Comment: While questions about product selection don't fit with the Stack format, I'll give you a hint: "polarizing plug" or "polarizing key"

Comment: I have been searching exactly those terms; and it's possible this just 'doesn't exist'.

Comment: The manufacturers of the header also manufacture such plugs.

Comment: I find nothing like that for sale on eBay...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, questions about how to select products are fine.

Comment: This question was asked before, and answered, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/262852/117785

Comment: The fact that you can't find them on eBay doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [epoxy for keying box headers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262850/epoxy-for-keying-box-headers)

Comment: Uhh... the minimum order at what was linked is $1088.78, in an absurdly high quantity. That question also did not come up when I searched this site before asking the question.

Comment: Also, the question is about what type of glue/epoxy/filler to put in, not what item can be purchased and be removable.

Comment: @ThePhoton -- edited to unshopify :)

Answer (score 2):

Found them!

[image: Polarizing Key]

They are available at http://www.frontx.com/pro/cpx079.html

Comment: Polarizing keys may be unique to a particular make and connector series - keys for one connector series may not fit another.

Comment: I understand; I haven't been able to find a name for the series shown in the image in the question other than '2.54mm pitch' or '0.1" pitch'. I was asking in reference to that particular series, and I haven't seen any demonstrable difference in any of the non-polarized brands (the holes seem to be standard, though the shape around the outside of connectors sometimes varies).

Comment: I would ditto the comments that polarizing plugs from vendor to vendor are quite different with regard to form and fit. Checkout SAMTEC as a possible source for your right angle connector. If I recall they show the plugs right on their catalog pages with the connectors.

Comment: I guess I should clarify then; I want plugs to fit 'generic' headers such as these, not brand specific in any way.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/302133511604

Comment: Like I said you are not going to find a generic solution. The plug are vendor and connector line specific. What works for a Samtec connector may just fall out of a TE/AMP connector.

Comment: That may be the case, perhaps, but they may work just fine. I'm not interested in getting locked into a proprietary line in any case, just want something that works most of the time.

Comment: The most generic solution you will find is the manually applied epoxy method. I use JB_Weld myself all the time for this. It's kind of a pain to apply but works well. It would be questionable in production trying to do 100 or 1000s. For those higher volume applications you go to the manufacturer and get the female header holes molded closed for your keying positions.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a >90% chance that these will work across any individual 2.54mm pitch connector like this, regardless of brand or series (provided they have a square opening and haven't deviated from the 'generic' connector).

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a Molex KK series or equivalent. They sell keying plugs for that series which will almost certainly fit a compatible "generic" connector:

[image: Molex KK series keying plug]

The Molex part number for this is 15-04-9209 but you may need a different part for other manufacturers connectors or different pin spacings.

I don't know where you are, not that it matters as this site isn't for shopping questions, but where I am I can order a pack of ten of these for £0.63 and have them delivered next day.