# USB-2 9 Pin Header

Tags: usb, connector, identification, usb-host

I am designing a carrier board for a SOM and I was planning to put one or more 10(9) pin headers on the board to connect to external USB connectors.
Most of these on existing motherboards have pin 9 removed for keying reasons.
I have looked at all suppliers but I cannot find a part that has that pin 9 removed!

[image]

Can anyone give me a pointer where I can find this part?
To be clear: I need the header for this that will go on the PCB...

UPDATE:
I contacted Samtec and they gave me a part number: 
HTSW-105-07-G-D-009
https://www.samtec.com/products/htsw-105-07-g-d-009

Comment: You might find this solution for connector "keying" interesting, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/262852/117785

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Special order from Samtec, Molex, or other manufacturer,  prices are reasonable even in small-ish quantitues like 1000 pieces.

For really small quantities get out your pliers and modify them by hand, the pins just pull out.

Comment: Pull the pin, or clip it off with dikes.

Comment: This is a board that will go into production, clipping the pin is not a preferred solution. See the update to the OP about a part number that has only 9 pins.

Answer (score 0):

Use  10 pin header 2x5 and pull out or cut off unused pin.